# Calabash - My device won't rotate

Tags: android, calabash, calabash-android

I'm discovering Calabash, using it with cucumber and I'm having an issue.

I started some code to test my basic app :

```
Scenario: I can see a button Test Button
  When I enter "Something" into input field number 1
  Then I wait
  Then I press the "Test Button" button
  Then I wait
  Then I should see text containing "Something"
  Then I go back 
  Then I rotate landscape
  Then I wait for 5 seconds
```

Everything works fine and everything is passed until I arrive on the device rotation step. It just doesn't work (doesn't rotate) and is treated as an "**undefined**" instead of passed and the very last line gets "**skipped**"

The test ends like this.

I checked everywhere and just can't figure out why it doesn't work.

Could anyone help me please ?

Comment: So does the UI rotate when that lines is executed? And if it is not is it because orientation is locked on the device/simulator?

Comment: It was indeed ! Too much focused on the code and not enough on the environment.. Thanks for the help =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comment - disable rotation lock.